# Access join of two subqueries

Tags: sql, join, subquery, ms-access-2013

I am constructing a simple database for an inventory system, with a barcode  reader.  I have one form to add inventory, and one form to remove inventory.  Each adjust add a column to the add or remove table.

I made queries for my add and remove that return the total value of each item, associated with the id for each item.  I want to join my add and remove tables so I can calculate the difference for a current quantity.

I am running into trouble with joining my add subquery and my remove subquery.

Add:

```
SELECT Items.description, Count(Trans_Add.s) AS Quantity
FROM Items INNER JOIN Trans_Add ON Items.ID = Trans_Add.s
GROUP BY Items.description;
```

Remove:

```
SELECT Items.description, Count(Trans_Remove.s) AS Quantity
FROM Items INNER JOIN Trans_Remove ON Items.ID = Trans_Remove.s
GROUP BY Items.description;
```

Whenever I try to assign alias for either in the from clause of my new query and join them it does not work.

Comment: Can you post your "new query" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Items.ID, Items.Description, (Items.TotalCount + A.Quantity - B.Quantity) as OnHandQty 
FROM Items INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Items.ID, Count(Trans_Add.s) AS Quantity
FROM Items INNER JOIN Trans_Add ON Items.ID = Trans_Add.s
GROUP BY Items.description
) A
ON Items.ID = A.ID
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Items.description, Count(Trans_Remove.s) AS Quantity
FROM Items INNER JOIN Trans_Remove ON Items.ID = Trans_Remove.s
GROUP BY Items.description
) B
ON Items.ID = B.ID
```

I made up a Field named `TotalCount` because you did not mentioned what is the Item Quantity in `Items` table. So, change it accordingly, that is, according to the
right field name for Item Quantity from `Items` table.

Comment: Thank you for the response and help so far.  I implemented what you gave me and I am now receiving a syntax error for "missing operator" in the query expression "items.id = a.id ..."

Comment: Your field name is ItemID as per select statement and in the ON clause you are using id, correct it to Items.ItemID

Comment: Sorry for that oversight, yes it should be Items.ID not Items.ItemID. But good thing it works for your now. GOD bless and happy coding!